# Mesh becomes extremely wrinkled around the hips and shoulders

Tags: rigging

I have been trying to fully model, rig, and animate my own character with Blender.  So far, it's been going great.  However, I have come across an issue that has impeded my progress.  Whenever I lift up a leg or arm, it looks okay until I put on a multiresolution modifier.  My mesh becomes extremely wrinkled, and looks terrible.  My gut tells me that it's in my weight paint, although after repeated weight paint combinations, it has resulted in no solution.  Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: Upload your modifier stack. Make sure the multires modifier is after the armature modifier.

Comment: Could you upload your .blend file on http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ to be able to help you?

Answer (score 1):

Moving the multires modifier below the armature modifier solved the issue.  :)